# How to implement a Login screen with Twitter Kit for Android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement a Twitter functionality inside my custom Android app by using their new Twitter Kit 3 API, but I cannot make it work.

I just followed this example: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/android/log-in-with-twitter

My MainActivity class is the following:

```
package gib.twitterpruebacliente;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Result;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Twitter;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterException;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterSession;
import com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Twitter.initialize(this);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
            // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "IT WORKS!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            // Do something on failure
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "FAIL!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Pass the activity result to the login button.
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

My XML activity main just have a TwitterLoginButton:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="gib.twitterpruebacliente.MainActivity">


    <com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have already added the permission on the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And I added the KEYS for my app in the strings folder:

```
   <string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_KEY">suP4TlwNI7xpwh3sK4x5fKldL</string>
<string name="com.twitter.sdk.android.CONSUMER_SECRET">oaAzoqtMlu5ZtY40LPdzfZTk5wNSTg6Lrnkgx5MPc4TTLbfzMZ</string>
```

[image: key]

But the app always enters on the failure section. How can I do?

[image: failure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. The problem was that I didn't have specified a callback URL. In order to do that, it is needed to vinculate the project to Firebase.

This is achieved by clicking Tools/Firebase/Authentication and following the steps. Next, the Firebase console gives you a Callback URL that must be specified on Twitter's API apps.